# Coefficient equality test for multinomial logit (preferably in R)

Tags: statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, multinomial-logit

If I want to test the equality of the coefficients of two IVs in the same regression (same DV) I can do a Wald test. If I want to test the equality of the coefficients of the same IV in two different regressions (*seemingly unrelated regressions* with different DVs), I can do [this kind of wizardry](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/testing-the-equality-of-coefficients-same-independent-different-dependent-variables/). But what if I need to compare the coefficients of the same IV for two different levels of a nominal variable in a multinomial logit regression? How do I test whether $\beta_1 = \beta_2$?

Let's say in:

```
multinom(formula = dv ~ iv, data = df)

================================================
                       Dependent variable:      
                  ------------------------------
                       dv_l1          dv_l2     
                        (1)            (2)      
------------------------------------------------
iv                    0.736***       0.658***   
                      (0.023)        (0.021)    

Constant             -5.757***      -4.396***   
                      (0.036)        (0.018)    

------------------------------------------------
Observations         245,698         245,698    
Log Likelihood     -21,432.162     -21,432.162  
Akaike Inf. Crit.   42,872.320      42,872.320  
================================================
Note:              *p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<0.001
```

How do I test whether the difference between the coefficients for `iv` is statistically significant (is 0.736 - 0.658 = 0.078 significantly different from zero)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you just need to extract out the coefficients, take their difference, and construct the standard error of that difference using the variance-covariance estimates of the parameters. Here is a quick example in R.

```
library(nnet)
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
birthwt$race <- as.factor(birthwt$race)
m1 <- multinom(race ~ bwt, data=birthwt)

v <- vcov(m1)
c <- coef(m1)
dif <- c[1,2] - c[2,2]
se <- sqrt( v[2,2] + v[4,4] - 2*v[2,4] )
dif/se #This is standard normal distributed
```

The `dif/se` is your test statistic (this is called a Wald test), and has a standard normal distribution, so you can look up a p-value the usual way.

One package in R that helps doing these tests is the `car` library. Here is how you would use that package to do the same statistical test.

```
library(car)
linearHypothesis(m1,c("2:bwt = 3:bwt"),test="Chisq")
```

You will see this does a $\chi^2$ statistic, but it is the same Wald test. If you do `pnorm(dif/se)*2` you will get the same p-value as the `linearHypothesis` function. The Wald test can be extended to testing multiple coefficient equalities, and one common one is to see if [*any* of the coefficients change](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Multivariable-Wald-to-test-equality-of-multinomial-coefficients-td4725319.html) across different levels of the dependent variable.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Very useful and instructional. Indeed a good topic for a blog post!